# whether a function returned in the child process can be captured in the parent process

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork, parent-child

I'm currently implementing the && function in a shell using C. For example, if we input cmd1 && cmd2, then cmd2 executes only when cmd1 exits successfully. I'm thinking about:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    char **args; 

    while(1) {
        printf("yongfeng's shell:~$ ");
        args = get_line();
        if (strcmp(args[0], "exit") == 0) exit(0);     /* if it's built-in command exit, exit the shell */
        if('&&') parse_out_two_commands: cmd1, cmd2;
        if (execute(cmd1) != -1)   /* if cmd1 successfully executed */
            execute(cmd2);       /* then execute the second cmd */
    }
}

int execute(char **args){
    int pid;
    int status;   /* location to store the termination status of the terminated process */
    char **cmd;   /* pure command without special charactors */

    if(pid=fork() < 0){   //fork a child process, if pid<0, fork fails
        perror("Error: forking failed");
        return -1;
    }

    /* child */
    else if(pid==0){             /* child process, in which command is going to be executed */
        cmd = parse_out(args);
        /* codes handleing I/O redirection */

        if(execvp(*cmd, cmd) < 0){   /* execute command */
            perror("execution error");
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    /* parent */
    else{         /* parent process is going to wait for child or not, depends on whether there's '&' at the end of the command */
        if(strcmp(args[sizeof(args)],'&') == 0){
            /*  handle signals */
        }
        else if (pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0) == -1) perror("wait error");
    }
}
```

So I'm using another function int execute(char ** args) to do the actual work. Its return type is int because I wan to know whether the command exits successfully. But I'm not sure here whether the parent process can get the return value from the child since they're two different processes.

Or should I decide whether to execute the second command in the child process, by forking another process to run it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not related to your question, but there are least two problems with `strcmp(args[sizeof(args)],'&')`

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
if(pid=fork() < 0){   //fork a child process, if pid<0, fork fails
```

to:

```
if((pid=fork()) < 0){   //fork a child process, if pid<0, fork fails
```

You're setting `pid` to the result of `fork() < 0`, not setting it to the PID of the child. So unless there's an error in `fork()`, this sets `pid` to `0` in both the parent and child, so they both think they're the child.

Regarding the return value of the `execute()` function: It will return in both the parent and child. In each process, it will return whatever was specified in the `return` statement in the corresponding branch of the `if` in `execute()`. Note that it `execve()` is successful, the child never returns, because it's no longer running this program, it's running the program that was exec'ed.

If the child wants to send success or failure information to the parent, it does this using its exit status, by calling `exit(0)` to indicate success, and `exit(some-nonzero-value)` to indicate failure. The parent can get the exit status using `waitpid`, and then return a success or failure indication from `execute()`.

Comment: oh, yes, I see. thank you. but actually my question is whether the value returned in the child process can be captured in the parent process. That is, whether I can write if (execute(cmd1) != -1) ? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing that happens in the child process is visible to the parent, except its exit status, which you can get using `waitpid()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. but here I still cannot understand why the execute function will return both in the parent and child process? If I want to implement the && function, should I just run one cmd in child, and another in parent if child exits successfully? I'm currently forking two children to do this.

Comment: When you fork, execution continues in both the parent and child functions. If they both execute a `return` statement or reach the end of the function, they'll both return. The child will return in the child process, the parent will return in the parent process.

Comment: However, when you use `execve`, you're no longer running the program that called `fork`. The child process is now running the program that was named, and `execute()` never returns in the child process. The parent process must call `waitpid()`, check the exit status, and return the success from `execute()`.